# Why gdb works incorrectly on gcc output?

Tags: c, gcc, gdb

Let's compile the following program with `gcc -g -O0 -o prog prog.c` and run `gdb` on it. If we go step by step, we will see that after line

```
4     switch (c) {
```

it goes straight to line

```
38    return 0;
```

which is wrong, because it first must go to line

```
32          break;
```

which is duly done on output produced with `clang -g -O0 -o prog prog.c`

**GCC version:** gcc (Debian 6.4.0-1) 6.4.0 20170704

**clang version:** 3.8.1-24 (tags/RELEASE_381/final)

```
int main(void)
{
  char c = '\x1a';
  switch (c) {
    case '\x18': /* C-x */
        break;
    case '\x12': /* C-r */
        break;
    case '\x13': /* C-s */
        break;
    case '\x10': /* C-p */
        break;
    case '\x0e': /* C-n */
        break;
    case '\x02': /* C-b */
        break;
    case '\x06': /* C-f */
        break;
    case '\x05': /* C-e */
        break;
    case '\x01': /* C-a */
        break;
    case '\x04': /* C-d */
        break;
    case '\x08': /* C-h */
        break;
    case '\x1d': /* C-] */
        break;
    case '\x16': /* C-v */
        break;
    case '\x1a': /* C-z */
        break;
    case '\x0d': /* C-m */
        break;
    default:
        (void) c;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: is not it `0x1a` instead of `\x1a`?

Comment: @dlmeetei I suppose these are equivalent

Comment: Because [gcc](https://godbolt.org/g/4t7aL2) and [clang](https://godbolt.org/g/z8Ck5s) generate different code for this example.

Comment: @ks1322 This should be the answer. Do you know how to fix gcc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gdb does not work incorrectly, it only steps over compiler generated code. For this dummy example which is doing nothing, gcc generates [this code](https://godbolt.org/g/4t7aL2):

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-1], 26
        movsx   eax, BYTE PTR [rbp-1]
        cmp     eax, 29
        ja      .L2
        mov     eax, eax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR .L4[0+rax*8]
        jmp     rax
.L4:
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
        .quad   .L2
.L2:
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

There is no corresponding code generated for `break` statements, so gdb can't walk over them because they does not exist.

On the other hand clang generated another [more verbose code](https://godbolt.org/g/z8Ck5s) for `break` statements. That's why you can walk over them:

```
main:                                   # @main
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 4], 0
        mov     byte ptr [rbp - 5], 26
        movsx   eax, byte ptr [rbp - 5]
        dec     eax
        mov     ecx, eax
        sub     eax, 28
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 16], rcx # 8-byte Spill
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 20], eax # 4-byte Spill
        ja      .LBB0_16
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rbp - 16] # 8-byte Reload
        mov     rcx, qword ptr [8*rax + .LJTI0_0]
        jmp     rcx
.LBB0_1:
        jmp     .LBB0_17
.LBB0_2:
        jmp     .LBB0_17
.LBB0_3:
        jmp     .LBB0_17
.LBB0_4:
        jmp     .LBB0_17
.LBB0_5:
        jmp     .LBB0_17
.LBB0_6:
        jmp     .LBB0_17
.LBB0_7:
        jmp     .LBB0_17
.LBB0_8:
        jmp     .LBB0_17
.LBB0_9:
        jmp     .LBB0_17
.LBB0_10:
        jmp     .LBB0_17
.LBB0_11:
        jmp     .LBB0_17
.LBB0_12:
        jmp     .LBB0_17
.LBB0_13:
        jmp     .LBB0_17
.LBB0_14:
        jmp     .LBB0_17
.LBB0_15:
        jmp     .LBB0_17
.LBB0_16:
        jmp     .LBB0_17
.LBB0_17:
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rbp
        ret
.LJTI0_0:
        .quad   .LBB0_9
        .quad   .LBB0_6
        .quad   .LBB0_16
        .quad   .LBB0_10
        .quad   .LBB0_8
        .quad   .LBB0_7
        .quad   .LBB0_16
        .quad   .LBB0_11
        .quad   .LBB0_16
        .quad   .LBB0_16
        .quad   .LBB0_16
        .quad   .LBB0_16
        .quad   .LBB0_15
        .quad   .LBB0_5
        .quad   .LBB0_16
        .quad   .LBB0_4
        .quad   .LBB0_16
        .quad   .LBB0_2
        .quad   .LBB0_3
        .quad   .LBB0_16
        .quad   .LBB0_16
        .quad   .LBB0_13
        .quad   .LBB0_16
        .quad   .LBB0_1
        .quad   .LBB0_16
        .quad   .LBB0_14
        .quad   .LBB0_16
        .quad   .LBB0_16
        .quad   .LBB0_12
```

If you want gcc to generate code for `break` statements you should alter you example to do at least something in `switch` statement. For example add one more variable `i` and change it's value in `switch` statement:

```
int main(void)
{
  int i = 0;
  char c = '\x1a';
  switch (c) {
    case '\x18': /* C-x */
        break;
    case '\x12': /* C-r */
        break;
    case '\x13': /* C-s */
        break;
    case '\x10': /* C-p */
        break;
    case '\x0e': /* C-n */
        break;
    case '\x02': /* C-b */
        break;
    case '\x06': /* C-f */
        break;
    case '\x05': /* C-e */
        break;
    case '\x01': /* C-a */
        break;
    case '\x04': /* C-d */
        break;
    case '\x08': /* C-h */
        break;
    case '\x1d': /* C-] */
        break;
    case '\x16': /* C-v */
        break;
    case '\x1a': /* C-z */
        i = 1;
        break;
    case '\x0d': /* C-m */
        break;
    default:
        (void) c;
  }
  return 0;
}
```